# ReactJS good practices using Hooks and Redux. Should I use useSelector in each component, or I should pass via props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I should use the same useSelector in each child component or I should pass the useSelector via props?

Both examples below works, I just want to know what is the best practice.

**Example passing via props:**

```
const FatherComponent = () => {
 const userId = useSelector((state) => state.user.id);

 return (
   <ChildComponent userId={userId} />
 )
}

const ChildComponent = ({userId}) => {
 return (
 <>{userId}</>
)
}
```

**or example repeating the useSelector:**

```
const FatherComponent = () => {
 const userId = useSelector((state) => state.user.id);

 return (
  <ChildComponent />
 )
}

const ChildComponent = () => {
 const userId = useSelector((state) => state.user.id);

 return (
  <>{userId}</>
 )
}
```

Comment: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I have asked for. ;D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Prefer having more UI components subscribed to the Redux store and reading data at a more granular level**

Just for the completeness, above is the recommendation from official redux site.

Full credits to Nicholas Tower who pointed to the page in the comments section.

> Prefer having more UI components subscribed to the Redux store and
> reading data at a more granular level. This typically leads to better
> UI performance, as fewer components will need to render when a given
> piece of state changes.
>
> For example, rather than just connecting a  component and
> reading the entire array of users, have  retrieve a list of
> all user IDs, render list items as , and
> have  be connected and extract its own user entry from
> the store.
>
> This applies for both the React-Redux connect() API and the
> useSelector() hook.

From the link - https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store